# How the read the Inclusion Probability coefficient of the Causal Impact package (R)?

Tags: r, r-package

I'm using the causal impact package in R to estimate the effect of a campaign. I want to know which one of my predictors are used by the model and how important these are. Here https://google.github.io/CausalImpact/CausalImpact.html I've red that you can look at the inclusion probability, but I find it hard to interpret these results. For example what is an inclusion probability of 0.6 saying? (and why do the bars have different colors?)

[image: Inclusion probability]

Comment: I have the same question. I'm guessing white stands for inclusion and black for exclusion from the model.